# Datepicker dateformat does not match with oracle database date

Tags: java, oracle, javafx, datepicker

I am trying to get date from jfxdatepicker but the resulting string format is not matching the column date format in the database. This is error that i am getting
java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

```
public void addEmployee(ActionEvent event) {
       RadioButton chk = (RadioButton)empsex.getSelectedToggle();// Cast object to radio button

       //System.out.println(empjoining.getValue());
       String ch;

       DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy");

       ch= dbcon.insertData("insert into employees (EMPLOYEE_ID,EMPLOYEE_NAME,FATHER_NAME,ADDRESS,AGE,CNIC,JOINING_DATE,LEAVING_DATE,EMAIL,TRANSPORT_ID,EMPLOYEE_TYPE,GENDER,PHONE_NUMBER) values (" +
                "'" +empid.getText()+"','" +empname.getText()+"','" +empfname.getText()+"','" +empaddress.getText()+"'," +
                "'" +empage.getText()+"','" +empcnic.getText()+"','" +empjoining.getValue().format(formatter) +"','" +empleaving.getValue()+"'," +
                "'" +empmail.getText()+"','" +emptransport_id.getText()+"','" +emptype.getText()+"','" +chk.getText()+"','"+empphone.getText()+"')");

       System.out.println(ch);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to format the value of empleaving DatePicker, assuming mpjoining.getValue().format(formatter) is doing what you need, the following should fix your problem :

```
ch= dbcon.insertData("insert into employees (EMPLOYEE_ID,EMPLOYEE_NAME,FATHER_NAME,ADDRESS,AGE,CNIC,JOINING_DATE,LEAVING_DATE,EMAIL,TRANSPORT_ID,EMPLOYEE_TYPE,GENDER,PHONE_NUMBER) values (" +
            "'" +empid.getText()+"','" +empname.getText()+"','" +empfname.getText()+"','" +empaddress.getText()+"'," +
            "'" +empage.getText()+"','" +empcnic.getText()+"','" +empjoining.getValue().format(formatter) +"','" +empleaving.getValue().format(formatter)+"'," +
            "'" +empmail.getText()+"','" +emptransport_id.getText()+"','" +emptype.getText()+"','" +chk.getText()+"','"+empphone.getText()+"')");
```